# Incorrect address returned by the Google Geocoder API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Geocoder API to get the address components for a geolocation. In the example below, the lat/long 39.35703, -81.30830 returns the address "WV-2, St Marys, WV 26170, USA" from the Geocoder API. However, that address is incorrect. When I search Google Maps for 39.35703, -81.30830, I get the correct address of 1 Heilman Ave, Belmont, WV 26134.

I created an issue in the Google Issue Tracker and they referred me here.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hoas9602/

The sample demonstrates getting the lat/long for 1 Heilman Ave, Belmont, WV 26134 and then going back to get the address components. Please let me know if I can provide further information or clarify the issue.

```js
var address = "1 Heilman Ave, Belmont, WV 26134";

$(document).ready(function() {
  getPosition();
});

function getPosition() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       var location = results[0].geometry.location;
       $(".output-lat-long").html(location.lat() + " " + location.lng())
        getGeocodedAddress(location, false);
      } else {
        $(".output-lat-long").html("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
}

function getGeocodedAddress(position) {
  var address = {
    streetNumber: null,
    streetName: null,
    city: null,
    state: null,
    stateAbbreviation: null,
    zip: null,
    county: null,
    country: null
  }

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ 'location': position }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     $(".output-geocoded-formatted-address").html(results[0].formatted_address);
      for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; k++) {
          if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "street_number") {
            address.streetNumber = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "route") {
            address.streetName = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "locality") {
            address.city = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
            address.state = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
            address.stateAbbreviation = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "postal_code") {
            address.zip = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
            address.county = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
          }
          else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "country") {
            address.country = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (address.country == 'US') {
      address.country = 'USA';
    }
    displayAddress(address);
  });
}

function displayAddress(address) {
 $(".output-street").html(address.streetNumber + " " + address.streetName);
  $(".output-city").html(address.city);
  $(".output-state").html(address.state);
  $(".output-zip").html(address.zip);
  $(".output-county").html(address.county);
  $(".output-country").html(address.country);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]"></script>

<div class="output-lat-long"></div>
<div class="output-geocoded-formatted-address"></div>
<div class="output-street"></div>
<div class="output-city"></div>
<div class="output-state"></div>
<div class="output-zip"></div>
<div class="output-county"></div>
<div class="output-country"></div>
```

Comment: [Issue Tracker Link] (https://issuetracker.google.com/128820283)

Comment: Looks like that address doesn't appear on the map (yet).  Seems like a map data problem to me and should be reported to google maps with the "report a data problem" selection (although it just looks like old data, that will probably be updated at some point and you will need to work around it until then).  As they said in their response, you should be able to use the data in the response to the geocoder, rather than the response to the reverse geocode request.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will work around it for now and hope that the data is corrected in the near future (although working around it may be difficult as there are times that the solution in question relies solely upon a reverse geocode lookup to get address components--however, we will make it work). Thanks for your help!